# How do I map a java.time.Duration to a Cassandra DB column with type time

Tags: java, cassandra, codec, duration

### Goal:

Map a java.time.Duration from JDK8+ to Cassandra DB column with type time.

### Situation:

I couldn't find any standard mapping or any codec (even in the maven-dependency with extra codecs) which has been able to do this.
It's a java 8 maven project with the datastax driver for Cassandra DB.

### Question:

Does anybody know a viable solution for this or any codec? If not, is it the best way to do a workaround via java.sql.time or is it even possible?

In the case I forgot some major details, please comment below.

Comment: Suggest rewording your question so it's not a library/tool request. Simply ask: How do I map a `java.time.Duration` to a Cassandra DB column with type `time`? More in the [help]. See also [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) *(Not my downvote)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use Cassandra type `duration` rather than `time`.

Pass or parse standard ISO 8601 strings using the `java.time.Duration` class.

```
Duration.parse( "PT1H30M" )  // Parse ISO 8601 string into a `Duration` object.
        .toString()          // Generate a ISO 8601 string from the `Duration` object.
```

## `Duration` is not a time

The [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline. It does *not* represent a time-of-day.

The Cassandra `time` type is defined as:

> Value is encoded as a 64-bit signed integer representing the number of nanoseconds since midnight. Values can be represented as strings, such as 13:30:54.234.

So you should not be storing a `Duration` value using a Cassandra `time` type.

You have other options.

One option is to store the standard [ISO 8601 textual representation of a duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. Example: an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`. This option is more truthful but the values cannot be compared or sorted in Cassandra, as they would just be text without alphabetical ordering being chronological. Also, see “Cassandra Duration” section below in this Answer.

The other option is to extract the two numbers used internally in `Duration`:

- A 64-bit integer, the count of whole seconds.
- A 32-bit integer, the count of nanoseconds in the fractional second.

If you insist, you could use those numbers to generate a value to store as a Cassandra `time`, but you’d be violating the semantics.

```
long fakeNanosSinceMidnight = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos( duration.getSeconds ) + duration.getNano() ;  // NOT recommended, but if you insist on abusing Cassandra semantics, here you go.
```

## Cassandra `Duration`

Cassandra [documentation says](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#durations) a `duration` type is built-in. I’m not a user of Cassandra so I cannot vouch for it.

The doc states that it accepts a standard ISO 8601 duration string as input. The `Duration::toString` method in Java generates such strings while `Duration::parse` parses the same.

```
String inputDurationForCassandra = duration.toString() ;
```

And parsing.

```
Duration duration = Duration.parse( myCassandraDurationString ) ;
```

Be aware that Java uses the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class for days (generic 24-hour chunks, not calendar days), hours, minutes, and seconds. The [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class represents years, months, days. It usually does not make sense to conjoin the two concepts. But if you insist, you can use the [`PeriodDuration`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project library.

Comment: Absolutely true, recognized the difference just now...
The documentation of apache cassandra states that there should be a duration type already:
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html

But I couldn't create a field with this type neither could I find any information about the Apache Cassandra version on this page which the article relies on so I could check whether my version is too old.